# How to send data back to the Page

Tags: angular, ionic3, server-sent-events

I am currently developing a POC Ionic application that streams data from an SSE Rest API.

I have a page to display the data which calls the provider and passes it a Device Name to read from. 
I have the Data in my console from the SSE stream however I am unable to figure out how to send this data back to the Welcome Page to display to the user.

```
scanForData(mac, token) {
// Open a connection
let stream = new EventSource(apiURL + 'gap/nodes?event=1&mac=' + mac + '&access_token=' + token);

// When a connection is made
stream.onopen = function() {
  console.log('Opened connection ');
};

// A connection could not be made
stream.onerror = function (event) {
  console.log(event);
};

// When data is received
stream.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
  this.WelcomePage.newData(); //this doesn't work (Undefined)
};

// A connection was closed
stream.onclose = function(code, reason) {
  console.log(code, reason);
}

// Close the connection when the window is closed
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
  stream.close();
});

}
```

I am learning Angular/Ionic as I am doing this, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use of an observable and the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) would be the way to do that.

Comment: Create a variable in the provider for storing the value you receive, whose value is initially set as false,once you get the your values update the corresponding value in the provider,And in home page simply access the value directly from provider